# Script to get a database from a remote server and deploy locally

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, dump

I want to use a script that will get my database from a remote server and automatically deploy locally.
Desired Algorithm:

1. Get base
2. Remove the previous `drop database localDbName`
3. Create a new `create database localDbName`
4. Expand my dump `use localDbName; source / var / www / html / TEST $ currentDate.sql`

I tried to implement this with bash but it didn't work. At the last step, the script stops working, the term stops waiting for input.

Tell me how to fix it. Or advise a working script in bash or another language

```
##!/bin/sh
remoteDbUser="remoteDbUser"
remoteDbName="remoteDbName"
localDbName="localDbName"
localPort="3306"
currentDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M)

ssh test@123.123.123.123 -p 123 "mysqldump -v --insert-ignore --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction=TRUE -u $remoteDbUser -p $remoteDbName" > /var/www/html/TEST$currentDate.sql
mysql -uroot -proot -h127.0.0.1 --port="$localPort" -e"source /var/www/html/TEST$currentDate.sql" --show-warnings $localDbName;
```

Comment: For starters, change `#!/bin/sh` into `#!/bin/bash`; after all, thta's what your tag expresses.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given script? What have you tried to resolve your problems?

Comment: At the last step, the script stops working, the term stops waiting for input.